# Empty array as default for active_record serialized attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, serialization, activerecord, attributes

I have an active record model:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :tags, Array
end
```

and in the migration the tags column is declared as

```
t.text :tags, :default => []
```

but when I try to create a person

```
Person.new
```

I get the error

```
ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch: added was supposed to be a Array, but was a String
```

How do I set the default to be an empty array in the migration?

NB: I know I could do this using after_initialize but I prefer to set defaults in migrations

Comment: Instead of after_initialize, try the default_value_for plugin: https://github.com/FooBarWidget/default_value_for

Comment: Note that you can't set a default on a TEXT column in MySQL, and potentially others.

Comment: coreyward: interesting, I didn't know about that. It looks like it's only a problem on windows though http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25520

Comment: paul: the default_value_for plugin looks quite tidy, if I can't find a way to do it with migrations then I think I'll go that route

Comment: I the same problem on a `string` column which I serialize as `Array`. An empty array would result in an empty string `""`. The problem was that the column had `null: false` and `serialize` wants to serialize `[]` as `nil`. When it cannot, it uses `""`, but then it can't deserialize correctly.

Answer (score 8):

There is an option to specify the class you want to store objects as. Try this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :tags, Array
end
```

Comment: ah, good catch, that should've been in the original post. I do already have this specified, no dice.

Comment: In the latest Rails, you specify it with `type:`, so `serialize :tags, type: Array`.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds rather like you've hit a framework bug or something else is interfering with your migration; I just tried building the above with Rails 2.3.10 and can instantiate objects without problems. However, I note that YAML is used for serialisation, so:

```
t.text :tags, :default => [].to_yaml
```

...might do the trick. Both migrations seemed to behave equally in my test application.

Comment: yeah, I gave that one a go, it gets turned into "" in the schema instead of "--- []\n\n"

Comment: Since I can't replicate this fault on Rails 2.3, it's either a Rails 3 problem or something wider up with your application. Just in case comments elsewhere about text columns are on the mark, though, have you tried using "t.string" instead of "t.text", with all other code as originally written, just as an experiment? Oh, and have you tried *without* the "Array" class specifier on the 'serialize' call?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and solved it by removing the default value.
ActiveRecord will treat nil as [] when you begin to add values to the array.

```
Migration:
t.text :tags

Model:
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :tags, Array
end

Usage:
p = Person.new
p.tags << "test"
```

This works because Rails will treat nil as [] for the array.